# Is there a way I can let the camera zoom but not rotate?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit

Is there a way I can let the SceneKit's camera zoom but not rotate? And how can I delimitate the maximum and minimum zoom the user can do with the camera?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by zoom – if you mean to do the same thing as 'zooming' a camera lens, you want to modify the `yFov` and `xFov` (field of view) attributes of the `SCNCamera` object. The camera stays in the exact same location, but changes its field of view like a zoom lens.

I cannot see how you can rotate the camera while zooming it – I’d need to see more context of where you’re using the camera. If you don’t touch the `SCNNode` the camera is attached to, you can’t possibly rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about user camera movement with `allowsCameraControl`, right? I don't think that's really meant to be the basis for a sophisticated user camera movement scheme, more of a simple debugging aid. If you really want fine control over how the user can move the camera, you're best served by creating your own camera node and moving it / changing its properties in response to whatever user input you want to handle (gesture recognizers, game controllers, etc).

I suppose you might be able to constrain the automatic user camera by implementing a scene renderer delegate `willRenderScene` method. You'd have to get the current `pointOfView` node, check its position and camera parameters, and change them if they're outside whatever bounds you want. But A) I'm not sure this would work, and B) it's probably not a great idea — it's sort of like messing with the internal view hierarchy of a system control class.